# finding prime numbers between 1 to 20 code not returning prime number 2,what is the correct algorithm?

Tags: python, primes

Finding prime numbers between 1 to 20

```
a = []
for i in range(2,20):
    for j in range(2,20):
        if((i % j) == 0):
            break;
        else:
            a.append(i)
return a
```

This is the output I got -

```
[3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19]
```

I expect 2 should also be included in the output

Answer (score 3):

You misplaced the `else`, which makes the sieve dysfunctional. In addition the inner loop should only iterate until `j == i - 1`. The correct code would look like this:

```
a = []
for i in range(2,20):
    for j in range(2,i):
        if((i % j) == 0):
            break
    else:
        a.append(i)
return a
```

The difference: in the original code any `i` for which a `j` is found, such that `i % j != 0`, will be appended to `a`. With the corrected code, `i` will only be appended, if the inner loop isn't terminated by a `break`. Also your code tests for divisibility for all numbers in the range `[2, 20[`, but even primes are divisible by themselves, which is why 2 wasn't part of the output of your code.

Comment: @TimPietzcker fixed. I forgot to correct the inner loop to only iterate until `i - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the two loops - `i=2` and `j=2`. The if condition is then true and therefore the inner loop stops without adding 2 to `a`.

Comment: Then what is the correct algorithm for finding all primes?

Comment: Technically correct, but even with that fix the code still isn't a functioning sieve

Comment: @Umang there are many correct algorithms for finding all primes. This is the reason you code does not work

Comment: @TomRon can you send me the link of other algorithms, please if possible

Comment: @Umang https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dsieve+of+Eratosthenes

Comment: @ChrisCharley Thanks, mate!